# Vim CommandT- like search for strings

Tags: string, search, vim, grep, ack

Is there a way in vim to search (grep/ack etc..) for strings in files in a similar fashion like one would do in CommandT?

So say that I invoke the search window. Possible matches for the string I wrote so far will start to show while I continue typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any native (as in `:set findasyoutype`) way to do exactly what you want.

But there's a plugin for that ! Well, at least three:

- [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) provides this feature through its `:LustyBufferGrep` command. It requires Vim to be compiled with Ruby support.
- [CtrlP](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/) too, provides this feature through the `line` extension.
- You can also try [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) which I've never used.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason for the downvote? Not enough details? Proposing to use a plugin instead of a native feature?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but as far as I can tell you can't search in multiple files with FuzzyFinder. Or I have not found how. You can use fuzzy search in a single file, or to open a file in your path, but not to find text in multiple files.

Comment: Well yes, as I wrote I've never used FuzzyFinder so I have no idea if/how it does that but LustyExplorer searches through all available buffers. CtrlP is limited to the current buffer.

Comment: Lusty and CtrlP provide this for opened buffers and not uopened ones. However CtrlP seems very interesting with its extension capability!! will def look into it! (Btw.. i upvoted :) )

Comment: there is also https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim that provides this functionality, but it is not very interactive.

Comment: There are many ways (native or enhanced) to search the content of files on your system in Vim. The native `:Grep` or `:VimGrep` coupled with the quickfix window would be the 1st choices, `ack.vim` is great too and there are [many other plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438) that try to make that task easier. This part of your question is very easy. But you want a fuzzy search interface and AFAIK, the only ones that add fuzzy matching to regular searching are the ones in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it looks like in CommandT, but if you issue the command `:set incsearch` (or put it in your .vimrc), once you search as usual, using `/`, vim highlights the first found item.